# Access Application.Quit not working, SharePoint Web Database

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, vba

In my database (Access 2013, .accdw), I am checking the user's current version in the Form_Open event.  If it is not up to date it triggers an external command to download a fresh copy and then is supposed to close itself to allow for the update.  The problem is that after Application.Quit is triggered, access closes but instantly reopens, blocking the download.  I've stripped out all the code I can to isolate the problem.

```
If 1 = 1 Then
Application.Quit
End If
```

Simplified pretty far, right?  It should always just close as soon as the form is opened.  With this as the only code in my Form_Open event which is the only code in the form, it still closes, reopens, and then closes again.  Docmd.Quit has the same effect.  I've tried too many variations to enumerate.  In a button this code works fine, but I need it to run the check before it loads any data (the linked tables may be being altered while we change versions). 
Any ideas how to make it stay closed the first time it closes?

Comment: It reopens because your external code (.bat file ?) reopens it. It's not an Access problem.

Comment: what is your external code/app?

Comment: No, please read again.  This is the ONLY code in the form.  When I simplified, I eliminated the call to the outside file and even the creation of the outside file.  There is no external code in the test scenario.  That was my first thought too.

Comment: Try adding a `docmd.close` before the `Quit` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it reopens because your external code (.bat file ?) reopens it. It's not an Access problem. Have you checked the numerous tools you can find for *Access automated client deployment* ? Here are the first 2 I found:
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3286111/Automatically-Deploy-a-New-Access-Client.htm
http://www.devhut.net/2015/06/30/ms-access-deploying-your-database-front-end-to-your-users/

Comment: No, please read again. This is the ONLY code in the form. When I simplified, I eliminated the call to the outside file and even the creation of the outside file. There is no external code in the test scenario. That was my first thought too.

Comment: OK, sorry I had not seen it was a SharePoint web db.I will delete my answer, since it's totally out of scope in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me in a Form_Open(), but then this is Access 2010 and no Sharepoint.

You may have better luck by [Creating an AutoExec macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-macro-that-runs-when-you-open-a-database-98ba1508-dcc6-4e0f-9698-a4755e548124#) that calls an initialization function that does the version check, instead of having a form open automatically.

If the version check is ok, then open your start form from the function.

Comment: Well, that reveals some interesting information!  I set my display form option to "none" so no form code would run,  created the autoexec macro, and had it call a public function with only one line of code in it.
`msgbox "auto"`
I saved, closed, and re-opened and was greeted with two message boxes that said "auto" instead of one. I tried it again using a macro "MessageBox' and got the same result. So my problem is that something is causing the system to double dribble! I think it's a problem with linking to SharePoint. Like when it reaches out to get info from the server, the server resets it.

Comment: I just verified that my original code and many of the other attempts I made, including your AutoExec macro idea, work fine in a non-SharePoint database.  
So this isn't the solution but at least it turned me in a better direction.  Thanks

Comment: Huh, crazy stuff. I wish you luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

The easy work-around is to always fetch the current version and then launch it.

This way there's no fuzz and the user always run the latest version.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would accomplish that.  The "accdw" means this is a SharePoint web database.  The built in procedure places a copy of the database in the user's default directory and locates an XML shortcut wherever the user directs.  If I alter the XML file, it auto-corrects itself the next time the user uses it to access the web database.

Comment: Oh, I'm not familiar with that behaviour, so you are probably right.

Comment: Thanks anyway.  It seems web databases are not very well documented.  Judging by the small number of questions out there I'm guessing not many organizations are using them.  I think I know why that is!